# Can I use Styled Components css`` method inside render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I know it is not recommended to define styled components inside the render function (or inside stateless function components) because of the performance issues. However, I wonder if using  the `css` method in a render function will also affect the performance negatively?

```
function Component = ({children, ...props) => (
    <div css={`margin-bottom: 1rem`}>{children}</div>
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `style`?

Comment: @MattCarlotta, I want to use ThemeProvider that comes with Styled Components.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, it appears that the css prop is similar to creating a memoized `styled.element` component. Component re-renders don't recreate the class name and state/prop manipulations act exactly same as a standard styled component -- when CSS properties have been altered, it either generates a new class or reuses an old one depending on how the CSS was changed. That said, the major downside to this approach would be that it requires `babel-plugin-styled-components` or `babel-plugins-macro` plus `styled-components/macro` to be added to your dependencies (if using `styled-components/macro`, **it has to be imported into EACH file**) which may or may impact application compilation times and make your application larger.

So, if you're OK with the above, then you shouldn't notice too much/any application performance difference. But, is it really worth the extra dependency/dependencies plus additional babel configuration to save yourself from doing this:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export default styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
`;
```

which achieves the same result as above, but with less dependencies/less configuration/less effort. I don't know, that's up to you...